# CRM Dynamics Power Apps Patch to Deactivate Views Not Deactivating Views

Tags: view, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, patch, powerapps

I have created a patch in our dev environment. This patch includes several views which need to be deactivated in our test and production environment. After I deployed the patch, the views were not deactivated in the test environment. Do patches not deactivated views or am I missing something? Thanks.

I tried looking for unmanaged layers that might be the culprit but did not see them. I cannot find any documentation regarding deactivating views via solution patch.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you have to do a solution rollup in order to deactivate the views. Pushing a patch will not deactivate the views.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).